# Passing references as function arguments doesn't work

Tags: c++, reference, sfml

I have code like this(all made for a minimal, reproducible example):

```
enum class gameState{
Normal,
Special};

class Piece{
public: Vector2i position;
int shape;};

class Board{
public: int array[8][8];
std::vector<Piece> f;
Board() : f(std::vector<Piece>(32)) {}; };

void promotion(int shape, gameState &state, Board &b){
state = gameState::Special;
b.array[b.f[0].position.x][b.f[0].position.y] = shape;
b.f[0].shape = shape;};
```

And then I try to call them in main:

```
int main(){
gameState state = gameState::Normal;
Board b;
promotion(1, state, b);
return 0;};
```

The problem is that it seems to correctly pass by reference for `gameState state` object, it doesn't modify `Board b` object, which isn't supposed to happen. How can I correctly pass `Board b` by reference (or a pointer)?

P.S.: `Vector2f` is simply a 2D vector the SFML library uses.

Comment: `Board() = f(std::vector<Piece>(32)) {};` ?  Doesn't compile for me (`g++` or`clang++`).

Comment: My bad, = was supposed to be :

Comment: Why do you think `b` hasn't been modified?

Comment: I print out and it doesn't change.

Comment: Also note that you're passing floats as array indices with `b.f[0].position.x` etc.  Please provide a proper [mcve] that you've compiled and tested yourself.

Comment: Again, a typo, in my program I use Vector2i, an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Board in your code is being (CORRECTLY) passed by reference to promotion function.
Are you sure it is not changed after function call?
What it prints if you do:

```
int main(){
    gameState state = gameState::Normal;
    Board b;
    std::cout << b.array[b.f[0].position.x][b.f[0].position.y] <<std::endl;
    promotion(1, state, b);
    std::cout << b.array[b.f[0].position.x][b.f[0].position.y] <<std::endl;;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Well, I figured it out.It was just that `b.f[0].shape = shape;` should be at the beggining of the function, since it's different before.